# How to get OS edition in UWP

Tags: windows, operating-system, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to retrieve OS edition like "Windows 10 **Home**" or "**Pro**" etc in UWP application (***Universal Windows Platform***). Is there any method to get this done.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For what purpose do you want the string? Just curious.

Comment: The fact that you have @PeterTorr-MSFT replying to your message like that tells me that this is probably not possible at the moment with the current UWP SDK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently available in a UWP app unless you use the desktop bridge and AppServices to communicate with an traditional Win32 app that can access this.

Comment: @HariKiran whether you use C++ or C# you still only have access to the same platform APIs and they don't expose it.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with Windows 11 and Windows Server 2022 using the [ProductName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo.productname?view=winrt-20348#Windows_System_Profile_AnalyticsVersionInfo_ProductName) property inside AnalyticsVersionInfo class however currently there's a bug that reports it as Windows 10 {edition} instead of Windows 11 {edition}.